# Adding a menu item in menu remove menu item next to it

Tags: php, wordpress

I am facing this problem for the first time in my development career.

I am working on a wordpress project which has a lot big menu. (around 150 items)

I cannot add more then 90 menu items. If i add more then 90 it remove the last menu items and only keep the first 90 menu items.

I googled the issue and found nothing helpful.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please add more detail so that we can help u

Comment: Hi,  What more details do you need ?

Comment: I can't add more then 90 menu item. if i do it only keeps the first 90 and remove the others.